# Complementary subspace of $M=(p(2x)=p(x)) ,p\in P_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Can anyone please help me with:
Find a some base for complementary subspace of
$$M=(p\in P_4 : p(2x)=p(x+1)), $$

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Is $M$ the subspace of all polynomials in $P_4$ that satisfy the condition $p(2x)=p(x+1)$? If so, have you verified that it is a subspace? What inner product are you using on $P_4$?

Comment: M is the subspace of all polynomials in $P_4$. I don't have to check is $M$ subspace of $P_4$.

Comment: I don't understand. $M$ can't be all polynomials.

Comment: @OliverJones, "$M$ is the subspace of all polynomials..." is obviously wrong, but "complementary subspace"  can be *a* complementary subspace in the sense of $P_4 = M\oplus M'$ without  inner product required.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Okay, I see.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: take a generic element of $P_4$,
$$p(x) = a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4.$$
The condition  $p(2x)=p(x+1)$ gives a set of linear relations between the coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$ required for $p\in P_4$. Namely, equating the independent terms, $a = a+b+c+d+e$. Do the same for the terms in $x$, $x^2$,...